# how do I evaluate elisp in a certain buffer from batch mode?

Tags: emms, batch-mode

I want to evaluate some elisp with batch mode, but it only works in a certain (type-of) buffer.  Specifically

```
emacsclient --eval "(emms-playlist-mode-play-smart)"
```

This command only works on an emms-playlist-mode buffer, so I'd like it to locate one in the current emacs server and execute there.

Comment: `emacsclient --eval "(with-current-buffer \"your buffer name\" (emms-playlist-mode-play-smart))"` should work. Maybe, you need `(get-buffer-create \"...\")` instead of `\"your buffer name\"`.

Comment: This was helpful, as it prompted me to find a way to bring the playlist "to the front" before calling functions on it.  In this case it was `emacsclient --eval "(emms-browser)"  --eval "(emms-browse-by-album)"  --eval "(emms-browser-goto-random)"  --eval "(emms-browser-add-tracks-and-play)"`.  Now EMMS works with my macbook's media buttons!

Comment: Nice to read that you solved your problem. You should add your solution and accept it. This marks the question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: I will, but I'll wait and see if anyone wants to post a more general solution and get free internet points for it :)